# How to get selected row index in devexpress gridcontrol?

Tags: c#, devexpress, gridcontrol, devexpress-gridcontrol

I have devexpress gridcontrol which looks like that:
[image]

I have click event on this red X button:

```
private void delete_button_ButtonClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ButtonPressedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

How can get there row index where this button is ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access rows on `GridControl`, since this is just a container for the views.
As I can see from your picture you're using `GridView`. When you press the delete button, focused row changes and you can access it via `FocusedRowHandle`.

```
private void delete_button_ButtonClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ButtonPressedEventArgs e)
{
  var gv = myGridControl.MainView as GridView;
  var index = gv.FocusedRowHandle;

  gv.DeleteRow(index);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [GridView.FocusedRowHandle](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.FocusedRowHandle.property) property:

```
 view.DeleteRow(view.FocusedRowHandle);
```

Comment: and how can I get row index?

Comment: P.S it is not gridview, it is gridcontrol